# Circle with inset shadow and gradient

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow

I wonder how to achieve the following effect. A circle with an inset shadow that also has a gradient.

[image]

I managed to get an inset shadow but with even color. I would need a gradient on the inset I think.

```
Container(
    height: 300,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color(0xffa3b1c6), // darker color
        ),
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color(0xffe0e5ec), // background color
          spreadRadius: -12.0,
          blurRadius: 12.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Gives the following:

[image]

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L97

Comment: can you share a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design like that is called Neumorphic design.

The central point of Neumorphism are shadows, which are giving the interface this feel of a surface carefully carved with a spherical drill.

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(bevel),
      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: bevel,
          offset: -blurOffset,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: bevel,
          offset: blurOffset,
          color: Colors.grey.shade400
        )
      ]),
  child: child,
);
```

The above code creates a white bevel for light and a dark one for shadow.

But [this medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/neumorphic-designs-in-flutter-eab9a4de2059) shows how you can do it better.

There's also this nifty library that I use called the [neumorphic container library](https://pub.dev/packages/neuomorphic_container) that helps to handle this for me.

EDIT: @nilsi shared a much better library that makes neumorphic design simple in flutter: [flutter_neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)

Comment: That helped me solve the issue. I used this library instead: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic